# Determinants and unique solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this section of my text and I'm a bit confused as to why we're finding the determinant of the system to see if the solution is unique:

[image]

Why does a nonzero determinant imply a unique solution?

Here is some relevant text I think?:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Jwan622, have you learn about Cramer's rule? The first proof of this rule in Wikipedia can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If $\det A \neq 0$, then $A^{-1}$ exists.

---

Suppose there are two different solutions to the equation $Ax=b$, say $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$, then:

$$Ax_1=Ax_2=b$$

More importantly,

$$Ax_1=Ax_2$$

Since $A^{-1}$ exists I can multiply both sides of the equation above by it to get,

$$x_1=x_2$$

So, we must conclude that there cannot be two different solutions.